# Using git filter-branch to modify tag messages

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

How can I use `git filter-branch` to modify tag messages? Using the `--msg-filter` option appears to only modify regular commit messages, but not messages of annotated tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  But that doesn't matter, because there's no point.

What `git filter-branch` does is to *add new commits* to a repository.  In general, you take an existing repository full of commits, identify one or more "bad" ones, and tell Git: *For every commit, extract that commit, fix it if it's bad, and then turn that into a new commit.*  If the new commit is 100% identical, bit-for-bit, to the original—if the filter made no changes at all—Git winds up *re-using* the original commit.  Otherwise, Git makes a new and improved commit, that has whatever was wrong with the original corrected and/or refers to the other *new* commits instead of the icky old ones.

*Your* job is to make a *new tag* (of type annotated tag) that refers to the same old existing commit as the previous tag (also of type annotated tag).  You don't need to add any new commits.

To do what you want, just make the new tag.  You'll need to rename or delete the old annotated tag first, to get it out of the way.  There is no command to rename a tag (if it's unpacked you can cheat, but if it has been packed this won't work), so that means you essentially need to delete the old tag.  Be sure to save the target *commit* hash first, because deleting the tag will make it impossible<sup>1</sup> to find again.

Hence:

```
git rev-parse existing-tag^{commit}
```

to get the commit hash ID, then:

```
git tag -d existing-tag
```

then:

```
git tag -a existing-tag hash
```

where the `hash` is the big ugly hash ID printed by the `git rev-parse`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you *can* find it, but it's much too hard, especially because `git fsck` won't save unreferenced tag objects into a `lost-found` directory like it does for unreferenced commits and blobs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. Unfortunately I have a bunch of tags that need modification. I just need to run a `sed` command against them to fix the message. Something like `git filter-branch --msg-filter` would have been perfect. Oh well, I guess I'll have to cook up a script to deal with it.

Comment: If you dig into the filter-branch script (it is a giant shell script) it actually has code to do this same sort of thing, except that it's changing the target of the annotated tags (by making new annotated tags) instead of replacing messages. But it will be a good guide. Search for the `--tag-name-filter` command line option and the variable and routines attached to that action.